# Pass result from one "for" loop iteration to next iteration?

Tags: python

I have a list of latitude/longitude coordinates and I want to create a line from them:

```
import time
import random

class Point:
    def __init__(self, lng, lat, neighbours):
        self.x = lng
        self.y = lat
        self.neighbours = neighbours

def find_neighbours(point):
        '''Simulate neighbour search in kdtree'''
        print(f'Searching for {point} in the tree')
        time.sleep(1)
        neighbours = random.randint(0, 100)
        return neighbours

class Line:
    def __init__(self, point_A, point_B):
        self.point_A = point_A
        self.point_B = point_B
        self.line = [
            point_A, 
            point_B,
        ]

def get_points():
    return [
    [51.11453, 17.10942],
    [51.11441, 17.10941],
    [51.11349, 17.10779],
    [51.11367, 17.10733],
    [51.1143, 17.10648],
    [51.11493, 17.10553],
    [51.11471, 17.10519],
    [51.11434, 17.10506],
    [51.11376, 17.10462],
    [51.11372, 17.10433],
    [51.11353, 17.1042],
    [51.11388, 17.10168],
    [51.11386, 17.10108],
    [51.11362, 17.10098],
    [51.11177, 17.10099],
    [51.11169, 17.10105],
    [51.11169, 17.10129],
]

def make_lines_from_points(points):
    lines = []

    for index, point in enumerate(points):
        try:
            next_point = points[index + 1]
        except IndexError: 
            # last point reached, so no need to make a line
            next_point = None

        if next_point:
            point_A = Point(
                point[1],
                point[0],
                find_neighbours(point)
            )
            point_B = Point(
                next_point[1],
                next_point[0],
                find_neighbours(next_point)
            )
            line = Line(point_A, point_B)
            lines.append(line.line)
    return lines

def main():
    points = get_points()
    lines = make_lines_from_points(points)
    print(lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code, I am turning every coordinate and the coordinate next to it into instances of `Point` class, and then create and instance of `Line` from such two points.

Upon initialization of each `Point` instance, point's neighbours have to be found and assigned to instance's `neighbours` attribute. This will potentially take a longer time.

With that in mind, I want to improve the `for` loop so that point B becomes point A in the next iteration, in order to avoid computing the neighbours again for the same point.

How can I do that?

Comment: So please correct me if I am mistaken, you want to perform find_neighbours(point) only once for each point. Is there a reason you don't find neighbors for all your points before obtaining the lines? If it has to remain in the structure you propose, You could use the index of your enumerate as a flag to indicate which values have been processed by find neighbors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def make_lines_from_points(points):
    lines = []

    point_A = None

    for index, point in enumerate(points):
        try:
            next_point = points[index + 1]
        except IndexError: 
            # last point reached, so no need to make a line
            next_point = None

        if next_point:
            if not point_A:
                point_A = Point(
                    point[1],
                    point[0],
                    find_neighbours(point)
                )
            point_B = Point(
                next_point[1],
                next_point[0],
                find_neighbours(next_point)
            )

            point_A = point_B

            line = Line(point_A, point_B)
            lines.append(line.line)
    return lines
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
def make_lines_from_points(points):
    lines = []

    saved_neighbours = None
    for index, point in enumerate(points):
        try:
            next_point = points[index + 1]
        except IndexError: 
            # last point reached, so no need to make a line
            next_point = None

        if next_point:
            point_A = Point(
                point[1],
                point[0],
                saved_neighbours if saved_neighbours is not None else find_neighbours(point)
            )
            point_B = Point(
                next_point[1],
                next_point[0],
                find_neighbours(next_point)
            )
            line = Line(point_A, point_B)
            lines.append(line.line)
            saved_neighbours = point_B.neighbours
    return lines
```